# How to make system call in python and store the output in a given output directory?

Tags: python, system-calls, stanford-nlp

I was working with Stanford CoreNLP, right now I'm running the coreNLP toolkit by using the following command from command-line:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09.jar:stanford-corenlp-2012-07-06-models.jar:xom.jar:
joda-time.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,
pos,lemma,ner -filelist file_list.txt -outputDirectory <OUTPUT DIRECTORY PATH>
```

This generates xml files with the required annotation. Now I need to using this command inside a function in python such that it stores the output in the output_dir. The function is like:

```
def preprocess(file_list.txt, ouptut_dir)
```

I read about system calls, and using subprocess, but I didn't quite understand how to use it such that it writes the output to the given output_dir.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really does not have much to do with `subprocess`, but rather on how Stanford CoreNLP is used from the CLI. Assuming that the `-outputDirectory` flag tells it where to store it's output, it's a simple matter of passing the correct CLI argument. Here is one proposition:

```
import subprocess

def preprocess(fname, output_dir):
    subprocess.check_call([
        'java',
        '-cp',
        'stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09.jar:stanford-corenlp-2012-07-06-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar',
        '-Xmx3g', 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP'
        '-annotators', 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner',
        '-filelist', fname,
        '-outputDirectory', output_dir
    ])
```

Comment: So, I'm trying to pass the fname and output_dir as absolute paths in the main like: if __name__ == '__main__':
preprocess(/Users/abc/Desktop/file.txt, /Users/abc/Desktop) but it gives me an error. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Python interface to Stanford Core NLP tools](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) instead of calling it via subprocess etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

def preprocess(input_file, output_dir):
    cmd = ["java", "-cp", "<the-whole-jar-mess>", "-Xmx3g", 
           "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP",
           "-annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner",
           "-filelist", input_file,  "-outputDirectory",
           output_dir]
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

Note the abbrevation I added to the commandline to not have to format all the jars into the command, you need to obviously replace that with the jar-list you are passing.